# Ask for location permission from framework?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location, info.plist

I'm writing a framework that uses `CoreLocation`. Is it possible to ask for location permission from the framework and the framework alone?

Or do I have to ask for location permission from the consuming app.

I'm asking this because any app that's `iOS 8` and above needs to include `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and/or `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key(s), with a description, in the app's `info.plist`.

**Quick Answer:**

You may ask for location permission from a framework (i.e. `self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization`) but the consuming app that is using said framework, **must** supply the `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`/`NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key(s) in it's `info.plist`.

Comment: Location can be asked from framework, but those description keys need to be added to the info.plist, otherwise location won't work.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in the post. But I was wondering if they MUST be included in the consuming applications `info.plist`. Because I'd much rather leave all permission requesting to the framework, and not make the consuming application have to handle asking for permission.

Comment: Yes, they must be included in the consuming app's info plist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its not the frameworks responsibility to ensure the containing app has the correct permissions to use the framework. So no its not possible.

The application needs to ask for the permissions.

Comment: Yeah it's looking like this is true, just wanted to be sure. Because I'd love it if the framework could handle all permission requests...

Comment: It would be great if the frameworks could specify the permissions needed to be included, and it just magically worked. But we're not there yet. Maybe someday! :)

Comment: I mean frameworks have `info.plists` so they really appear like they *should* be able to. But I guess I see why Apple doesn't want frameworks to have that kind of power. I guess frameworks are meant to be more generic and are in their own sandbox, so they shouldn't be able to make requests for consuming applications and different sandboxes. So it kinda makes sense, it's just a bummer :/ ;p